# Postgresql delete old rows on a rolling basis?

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete rows on one my tables that are more than 7 days old. What is the best way to do this? to make a cron job that runs every night or does PostgreSQL have built in features for doing something like this?

Comment: Is there a timestamp in the row?

Comment: the rows do have timestamp

Comment: Why delete the data, why not just query around it? And if you run the job nightly, you'll have data almost eight days old just before the job runs - why not run hourly, or every minute?

Comment: @Josh I could query around it, but the data will not be used anymore and it would just size to my database and it would make backups, restores take longer. I was going to run nightly since I'm not aware of how much of a performance drop my server will have while doing the deletes.

Comment: Consider adding partitions to the table in question ([manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)) if the table is big. It will allow you to delete old records very quick and avoid table bloat.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko thanks for the comment. I will look into it. I also ran into "Triggers" is that something I should also consider? can I schedule certain time when a function or trigger runs on pgsql?

Comment: @Arya Triggers are used as a reaction to some action in DB. Like: "write something to log table when someone changes client table." They cannot be launched by themselves, only as a response to other action that **triggers** them.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
delete from the_table
where the_timestamp < now() - interval '7 days'
```

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL does not currently have a built-in cron-like functionality, so I'd use the system's cron to run a suitable delete statement.  If you already have a btree index on the timestamp column, you might as well run the delete much more frequently than nightly, taking out small chunks at a time.  If you don't have the index, then running it nightly during off-peak times would be better.

If these don't have the performance you need, you could try partitioning.  But I'd do that as a last resort, not a first resort.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (for me) to schedule a DB job is to create a cron job, that executes a SQL script using `psql`.

[`Here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) you can read about `psql`. Use `-f` or `-c` to pass the SQL commands to `psql`.

Also it might be easier to write a PL/pgSQL function, that does your job and call it from `psql` with `SELECT my_function();`